# Redshift connection issue: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, amazon-redshift

We are connecting remotely to AWS Redshift instance.

We can successfully connect with Aginity workbench.

However, we cannot connect with a JDBC based tool (DBVisualizer).

We are using the Postgresql driver 8.4-703 (from Redshift docs).

SSL is required.

We use a non-standard port (1433).

Message returned is

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user xxxx
```

JDBC string is

```
jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxx.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:1433/dev?tcpKeepAlive=true
```

Debug is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "xxxx"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.onseven.dbvis.g.B.D.?(Z:1413)
    at com.onseven.dbvis.g.B.F$A.call(Z:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
SQLException: SQLState(28000)
```

UPDATED: I added SSL=true to the JDBC string..

New string:

```
jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxx.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:1433/dev?tcpKeepAlive=true&ssl=true
```

New debug is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:150)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.onseven.dbvis.g.B.D.?(Z:1413)
    at com.onseven.dbvis.g.B.F$A.call(Z:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
SQLException: SQLState(08001)
```

Obviously we've quadruple checked the password.

Comment: It *really* annoys me that Amazon say to use an old version of PgJDBC, instead of bothering to contribute to PgJDBC to enable proper Redshift support in current PgJDBC versions. They're acting like lazy parasites on the community.

Comment: Connection normally works fine with DbVisualizer. Are you using the same user as with Aginity? Have you tried using another tool (eg SQL Workbench/J) just to verify the connection? Perhaps try spinning up another Redshift on the standard port just to see if that's causing problems (although your security group setup seems OK since it's giving a specific error)?

Comment: Future searchers - no matter how you created your user (`MyUser`), you need to specify it in lowercase (`myuser`) (from [this table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable SSL option for JDBC, you have to download a redshift certificate and add it to your Java system truststore on your machine.

Here is the step:

- Download  Amazon Redshift certificate file from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem).
- Register Redshift certificate to your Java system truststore.

  - Run `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/keytool -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts -import -alias <alias> -file <certificate_filename>`
  - Run `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/keytool -keystore <keystore_name> -alias <alias> -import -file <certificate_filename>` to create your own truststore, If you don't have a permission to access cacerts.
  - The default password is `changeit`
- Specify the keystore and password in java VM properties

  - Open [DbVisualizer] -> [Preferences] -> [General] Tab -> [General]
  - Edit "Java VM Properties" section

    - `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=key_store_name_or_path`
    - `Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password`
  - Apply and restart

Some paths in the above commands might need to be changed for your environment. See [Amazon Redshift Management Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html#connecting-ssl-support-java) for details.

As for the authentication error, there might be unsupported password symbols in the Application level. It's worth a try to change a password to make it simple like containing only "_" for symbols.

Comment: Looks like a combination of both issues. The password characters may have been causing an issue with the application and SSL was failing as well.